# Notepad++: How to add carriage return (pressing enter key) after certain character

Tags: notepad++, css

I have a giant CSS file that has no carriage returns.
But I need to add carriage returns after the closing tags <kbd>}</kbd>.

Here is a sample:

> `#mvt-nascar #mvt-social li a.google-plus{background-position:-708px -460px}body#dispatcher.index #mvt-nascar #mvt-social li a.the-hub{background-position:-746px -460px}body#dispatcher.index #mvt-nascar .certifications{float:left;margin:0;border-left:1px solid #aaa}body#dispatcher.index #mvt-nascar .certifications ul li{float:left;margin:0 0 0 12px}`

It's like one giant run-on CSS file.  How can I add a carriage return after the } symbol

I've tried the search/replace using /n  but it just removed the <kbd>}</kbd> symbol.
What can anyone suggest?

Comment: Can't you just replace `}` with `}\n`? That would accomplish what you want.

Comment: Yeah, that should work - just make sure that you are in extended mode.

Comment: Perfect!  Worked great.  Thank you so much...

Comment: @Indrek I think you should make it as an answer

Answer (score 3):

You can simply replace `}` with `}\n`. That will preserve the curly brackets and add a line break after each one.