# How to add new line of text after a specific text in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

How to insert a new line of text after a specific text in Notepad++?

For example, I want to add a text in a new line after `<g:condition>new</g:condition>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for `new` and replace with `new\n`

Make sure '`new`' isn't going to pick up any incorrect results, e.g. you might have `newfoundland` in your text, you don't want it to replace that with `new\nfoundland` or

```
new
foundland
```

Comment: note it looks like a duplicate of this question http://superuser.com/questions/525031/notepad-how-to-add-carriage-return-pressing-enter-key-after-certain-charact

Comment: How about adding another text in a new line after <g:age_group>adult</g:age_group>? I want to add <g:identifier_exists>FALSE</g:identifier_exists>. in a new line. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Replace `<g:age_group>adult</g:age_group>\n` with  `<g:age_group>adult</g:age_group>\n<g:identifier_exists>FALSE</g:identifier_exists>\n`

Comment: @dess: If this answer resolved your question, please accept it. This could possibly help the community in the future.